# Blender 2.8 refuses to launch with OpenGL error even though GPU driver supports 3.3 and is up to date

Tags: opengl

Blender refuses to launch and displays this error:

[image: Blender error message]

I have a Geforce GTX 970 and the drivers are up to date. NVIDIA specs confirm that GTX 970 supports OpenGL 4.4 (https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/specifications).

Other system specs:
Win 10 64bit
Intel Xeon E5-1620 @ 3.60GHz 
16Gb RAM

Any ideas what is wrong and how to get Blender to work?

All ideas appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to use it via Remote Desktop?  I had the same problem when I tried that.  it fails because Remote Desktop doesn't support hardware acceleration.

Comment: Yes! This solved the issue. I did not think using remote desktop could have anything to do with it, but I was wrong. Thank you! Do you have any work around for this so that I could have the remotely controlled machine rendering without having to go physically to said machine to start the process?